# How to use HELM with Containerized Jenkins in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, kubernetes-helm, kaniko

I am implementing CICD with jenkins, Gitea and kaniko on Kubernetes cluster. Since the Jenkins is containerized, we have used kaniko to build and push the image to GCR registry. Now, I need to update the latest image tag in helm chart values file and install this with helm install on kubernetes cluster as a part of CD.

Somehow, I am not able to install Helm on jenkins container (it doenst allow root) or there is no helm plugin available in jenkins. How can I proceed with using helm in my CICD with containerized jenkins.

Comment: Your build runs in a pod in jenkins? If so, you can directly use a helm docker image as a utility and run helm commands. OR you can use a docker image which has helm installed in your pod template. Posting your jenkinsfile will help people provide better support.

Comment: @vijay, yes it runs in a pod in Jenkins. thanks, I would add helm installation step to template and try helm commands.

Comment: @vijay Did you fix that?How did you use helm command in jenkins pipeline?

Comment: we have created an image with jenkins, kubeclt and helm prebuilt in it.